# How to find the position of a sensor?

Tags: temperature, sensors

I found critical temperatures in my computer using [Libre Hardware Monitor](https://github.com/LibreHardwareMonitor/LibreHardwareMonitor).

[image: screenshot]

Sensor #3 shows 95°C and sensor #6 83°C. I tried to find out, where these sensors are. But I can not find it in the [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketAM4/PRIME_B550-PLUS/E16536_PRIME_B550-PLUS_UM_WEB_051420.pdf).

How can I find out, which component is too hot?

Comment: PC sensors are hit or miss. These probably do not exist at all yet the monitoring chip configuration does not properly disable the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the
[NCT6796D Data Sheet](https://www.nuvoton.com/resource-files/NCT6796D_Datasheet_V0_6.pdf).

On page 29, I find definitions for sensors #3 and #6 :

[image]

I can't find any other reference to these AUX entries.

In many cases, AUX temp sensors relate to sensors that you don't have
or are not connected.

These senseless Aux temperature look like an invalid reading
that should be ignored.